# Why won't my siamese cat leave me alone?

Tags: cats, psychology

Why won't my Siamese cat leave me alone? She has to be with me 24/7. No one else but me. 
I'm not complaining... I love her to pieces. Just feel bad for the others that she doesn't want to give attention to, and they try so hard to get her to like them.

Answer (score 2):

Siamese can be very dog-like in their focus on "their" people.

But many cats are hard to make friends with unless you are very patient. Some of the answers to other cat questions here will be applicable for folks who want to befriend her: sit down so you don't seem so huge, let the cat come to you, don't grab, consider using a toy that lets you play with the cat at a bit of a distance so it feels safer, let the cat decide whether it wants to be friends with you,